# Why does Cheesecake fail to execute pylint?

Tags: python, pylint

When I execute [cheesecake](http://pycheesecake.org/) it tells me that pylint had an error:

```
$ cheesecake_index -n natsort   
[...]
pylint ..........   0  (encountered an error during pylint execution)
[...]
```

But pylint is installed:

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 1.3.1, 
astroid 1.2.1, common 0.61.0
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
```

I think I have the latest cheesecake:

```
$ cheesecake_index --version
Cheesecake version 0.6.1 (rev. 176)
```

I use a Ubuntu 14.10 and installed cheesecake via `pip`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the cheesecake source. I ran into the same problem and created a pull request with the fix: https://github.com/griggheo/cheesecake/pull/11

Until they have fixed the issues and published the new version on pypy, you could try my fixed fork: https://github.com/micgro42/cheesecake/tree/fixLintVersionDetection (be sure to use the branch fixLintVersionDetection).
Should you still get the error with my fixed version, then please provide the log-file of your cheesecake run (`cheesecake_index ... -l LOGFILE --keep-log`)